# Convert timezone in php

Tags: php

I have these timezones. I want to get the current datetime depends on the given timezone. The user will select either one timezone. so need to return current time.

**ASKT

CDT

EDT

HST

MDT

MST

PDT**

How can i convert? Please help

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`DateTime` Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$time = time(); //Get the current time
$date = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru')); //Set a time zone
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n"; //display date

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London')); //set another timezone
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n"; //display data again
```

This, way you don't have to give the same timestamp as new argument every time like mishu's answer.

Comment: But I have only abbreviations (ASKT,...)

Answer (score 1):

[DateTime::setTimezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) would help you.

```
    <?php
    $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the class written by "the_dark_lord12001 at yahoo dot com" this will help you to get timezones from abbreviations & then you can use it
 with either date_default_timezone_set or DateTime class

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listabbreviations.php

Hope this help.

~K